# Why a holomorphic function has a regular value?

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry

Let $f : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function.
$y \in\ \mathbb{C}$ is said to be a regular value of $f$ if $\forall x \in f^{-1}(y)$ there exist an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ and an open neighborhood $V$ of $y$ such that $f|U$ is a diffeomorphism onto $V$.
Could someone explain me why such a function $f$ has a regular value ?

Comment: By diffeomorphic do you want real-diffeomorphic or complex-diffeomorphic?

Comment: I consider $\mathbb{C}$ as e real manifold, that is I identify $\mathbb{C}$ with $\mathbb{R}^2$ with a structure of real manifold.
So I think it should be real-diffeomorphic.

Comment: You need to assume $f$ is non constant.

Comment: If $f$ is constant and $\forall x \in \mathbb{C}$  $f(x)=c$ then every $y \neq c$ should be a regular value since $f^{-1}(y)=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you probably mean so that $f |U$ is a diffeomorphism onto $V$. (Just stating that there are neighborhoods that are diffeomorphic is not really a condition about $f$, and moreover it is always true...)

A reason such a regular value exists is because of local normal form for holomorphic functions: For $f$ a holomorphic function, and any point $x$ its domain, there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ and $W$ of $f(X)$, and biholomorphisms $\phi : D \to U$, $\psi : W \to D$ so that $\phi(0) = x$ and $\psi(f(x)) = 0$ so that $\psi f \phi : D \to D$ is $z^n$for some integer $n \geq 0$. Here $D$ is the unit disc.

So, $f$ is a local diffeomorphism at $x$ iff $n = 1$, which happens iff $f'(x)$ is nonzero. Now, the image of $\{ x : f'(x) = 0 \}$ under $f$ is a proper subset of $\mathbb{C}$, for example because $\{x : f'(x) = 0 \}$ is a countable subset of $\mathbb{C}$ (it must be discrete unless $f$ is constant, and discrete subset of $\mathbb{C}$ must be countable). Hence we can find some point $y$ so that for all $x \in f^{-1}(y)$, $f'(x) \not = 0$. Hence (again from the local normal form) there is a neighborhood of $x$ carried diffeomorphically by $f$ onto a neighborhood of $y$.

Alternatively, you can argue using Sards theorem. (But this theorem on local normal form has huge bang / buck ratio within complex analysis of one variable.)

Comment: You are right, I meant that $f|U$ is a diffeomorphism onto $V$.
I am trying to understand your explanation. Thank you.

Comment: @green feel free to ask any follow up questions if something is unclear.

Comment: Thank you very much, @AreaMan. That's very kind of you.

Comment: Could you suggest a book dealing with the local normal form of holomorphic functions ? Thank you very much. @AreaMan

Comment: @green I learned it from Rick Miranda's book on Riemann surfaces.

Comment: Pheraps, Instead of the local normal form for holomorphic functions, the inverse function theorem can be used.

Comment: @green Yes, you are right. Nice simplification. :)